# Calling a function of a reference to a function from within a class doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I've created a JavaScript class that gets a reference to a function as its constructor argument. This class has an init() function which calls the init() function of the referenced function which was passed to the constructor. However, this results in an error saying that this.aFunction.init() is undefined.

This is the code:

```
function AClass(aFunction) {
    this.aFunction = aFunction;
}

AClass.prototype.init = function() {
    this.aFunction.init();
}

var aClass = new AClass(function() {
    return {
        init: function() {
            alert('success');
        }
    };
});

alert('Before init');            
aClass.init();
```

I've put up a jsFiddle  at: http://jsfiddle.net/sbel/8cgpH/3/

Comment: Please also show the code here, and write your question with reference to your code.

Comment: There are no classes in javascript. `AClass` is a Constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to execute one function, see http://jsfiddle.net/8cgpH/5/

```
var aClass = new AClass(function() {
    return {
        init: function() { alert('success'); }
    };
});
```

That parameter you're handing to AClass is a function that will return an object that includes a method `init()` once it got invoked (you forgot to do that) - in other words: you're just handing a class but not an instance of that class.

```
var aClass = new AClass(function() {
    return {
        init: function() { alert('success'); }
    };
}()); // <---
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns something. The function itself doesn't have the property `init`. Call the function to get the object with its property (`aFunction` is not a function anymore but the object with `init` instead, so your naming would be a bit amiguous): http://jsfiddle.net/8cgpH/8/.

```
this.aFunction = aFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to *call* `aFunction` to get its return value. Right now what you're doing is looking for the property `init` in the function object itself, which doesn't exist.

```
AClass.prototype.init = function() {
    this.aFunction().init();
};
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/8cgpH/7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var aClass = new AClass({
        init: function() { alert('success'); }
});
```

your aFunction just a obj